# Etymology of "sh**hole"

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

What is the etymology of *shithole*? Did it originate from A) the orifice through which excrement is passed, or B) the hole in the ground intended for the disposal of such excrement?

(This is a serious question for professional research. You don't want to know the details.)

Comment: Where is the research part?

Comment: Yes. Please make the question more constructive (as it is, it can be answered by one liners), otherwise we'll have a bunch of know nothings come and turn this place into your vessel of research as soon as the question hits the multicollider.

Comment: _Wiktionary_? Really? You know you can just make up stuff there.

Comment: The word "shithole" should not be censored in the title. There is no consensus yet about censorship of titles, and it is going to interfere with searches.

Comment: @MetaEd The [consensus](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/561/what-should-we-do-about-question-titles-containing-vulgar-words) has generally been to avoid it, or censor it if necessary.

Comment: @Kitḫ Thank you for the link. I did read that article. Though it is perfectly relevant, I do not find a consensus therein.

Comment: I think the discussion regarding censorship should be discussed again because the sanitized title sounds too general, frankly boring, and will probably result in good answers being withheld because the question will be glossed over on the question list.

Comment: @MetaED: there's also [another ELU meta post about making titles not so vulgar](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/975/do-we-really-need-to-add-nsfw-in-question-titles). The consensus is to not put verbatim vulgarities in the title. As to rendering the title boring...I'm sure there are acceptable ways to spice things up.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I've seen that one also. There too, there is no consensus, only a modest majority, of a very small voting group. There are two substantial parties on opposite sides of the question. It would be great to get a consensus, but I don't think we get one by saying there is one.

Comment: @MetaEd You are welcome to answer, vote, or otherwise comment on the existing meta question, or come to chat to discuss it.  So long as it is the highest voted answer, it is how we will maintain the site.

Comment: I approved the edit but have now changed it back to the original.

Comment: @MetaEd It's not about consensus. The Powers That Be have spoken. We have to censor swear words and other things that offend from the titles. See [Should EL&U be removed from the multicollider?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/should-elu-be-removed-from-the-multicollider-etc)

Comment: @meta this is the policy; titles need to be censored, but the bodies (and comments) can be explicit as necessary. If you find this policy unacceptable, please refrain from participating on this website.

Comment: I see the original has been restored again.. This could go on for a long time.

Comment: And back again. I believe tis could be called an editorial war.

Comment: @tunny - just fyi: these things can get a little intense. One rollback per person is kinda acceptable. If one or two persons are doing most of the fighting, it's a war. This is nothin'.

Comment: Onelook only gives Oxford Dictionaries and Wiktionary. The former doesn't explain the etymology, and the latter just says it's "shit" plus "hole", which has the ambiguity mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The OED’s earliest citation for *shithole* is from the seventeenth century, and it’s given as ‘coarse slang’ for ‘the rectum or anus’. The earliest citation for *shithole* meaning ‘a toilet; a latrine’ is only from 1947.

Comment: That would be the OED’s mellifluous citation attributed to J. Lilliat in E. Doughtie *Liber Lilliati*, whihc is labelled *a* 1629 and reads: **‘Six shitten shotes did I shoote in thy mowth that I shot from my shithole.’** Thank goodness they have people doing such lovely research! :)

Comment: @tchrist: Yep, that's the one.

Answer (score 5):

Why wouldn't it be both? It seems like an obvious production from two easily-combined words, and the meaning, if it even matters, would be obvious in context.

Edit: [The Corpus of Contemporary American English shows 73 uses of it](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13929760), every time referring to a place, never once referring to an anus. So it would seem that the more common use of the word, and probably the original coining, refer to the hole-in-the-ground sense.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. As @BarrieEngland rightly points out, the original attested meaning was the rectum or anus, dating from way back in the early part of the 17ᵗʰ century.  The outhouse or latrine sense came much, much later. If you can antedate the latrine sense even to the 19ᵗʰ century, I’m sure the OED would love to hear from you, because all their citations for that sense are from at least the 20ᵗʰ.

Comment: The Corpus of **Contemporary** American English isn't the most appropriate source in this case, as it only dates to 1990.

Comment: Another point in Barrie's favor: the OP is asking about the history of the word, not its current meaning. Another question about this word (about what it currently means) would undoubtedly answer the place, not the anatomical region.

Comment: Can someone show if the "latrine" sense is derived from, or coined independently of the "anus" sense? I still think this particular word is actually two words formed trough typical, unsurprising combinations of productive words.